# How can I measure how long an embedded Vimeo video has been watched for?

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a Vimeo video embedded on my webpage and I want to record a Google Analytics event when a user has watched the video for 10 seconds. Is there a way to measure how long the video has been watched for?
For reference the player uses:
player.js - /* VimeoPlayer - v2.7.1 - 2015-06-26 */

Answer (score 1):

The `playProgess`event of the vimeo API does contain a `seconds` property.

So you can ask to listen to this event, and check for this property being more than 10.

```
function postMsg(id){
  var msg = {method:"addEventListener", value: 'playProgress'};
  var iframe = document.getElementById(id), cW;
  if(iframe) cW = iframe.contentWindow;
  if(!cW){setTimeout(function(){postMsg(id)}, 200); return;}
  cW.postMessage(JSON.stringify(msg), '*');
  }

var messageListener = function(e){
    if (!(/^https?:\/\/player.vimeo.com/).test(e.origin))
        return false;
    var evt = JSON.parse(e.data);
    if(evt.event==='ready') postMsg(evt.player_id);
    if(evt.event==='playProgress') onPlayProgress(evt.data);
    }

function onPlayProgress(data) {
    if(data.seconds > 10) doSomething();
    }

window.addEventListener('message', messageListener, false);
iframe.src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/theVideoId?api=1&amp;player_id="+iframe.id;
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/83Lq2288/1/)

Comment: Just to make it more complicated, what if the video is inside a modal which means it doesn't get added to the DOM until the modal is initalised with a click?

Comment: I guess you'll need to wait until the frame has loaded before being able to access its contentWindow, and therefore to talk to the vimeo API

Answer (score 0):

`<video>` elements [emit events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events). If your player uses `<video>` you can add event listeners for `timeupdate` events, or listen for `play`/`pause` events and handle the timing yourself.

Comment: vimeo player uses iframe, so you have to send them custom messages